# Reversed bullet chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I started working with highcharts. Now a problem I am facing is that the bulletcharts can’t be used for a dataset that is in descending order.

For example say we want to plot the ranking of a few companies. In this case the ranking is better the lower it gets. **So a Rank 10 is better than a Rank 15 and so on.**

*In this case I want my **graph to get reversed**. The target would be lets say 10. The min value would start from say 100 to 0. So you can see how this isnt possible.*

P.S: I know the

> reverse: true/false

property. But that simply flips the graph and I don’t want that/need that.
Thanks world.

[image: Mockup explaining my idea]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second y-axis with the same extremes as the first one, but reversed. Next, hide the first y-axis, calculate mocked y and target values and finally, set a custom formatter function for tooltip to show original values.

```
const MAX = 300;
const TARGET = 50;
const Y = 25;

Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        inverted: true,
        type: 'bullet',
    },
    yAxis: [{
        visible: false,
        min: 0,
        max: MAX
    }, {
        min: 0,
        max: MAX,
        reversed: true,
        ...
    }],
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(tooltip) {
            const point = this.point;

            return `<span style='color: ${this.color}'>●</span> ${this.series.name}: <b>${point.originalY}</b>. Target: <b>${point.originalTarget}</b><br/>`

        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: MAX - Y,
            target: MAX - TARGET,
            originalY: Y,
            originalTarget: TARGET
        }]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ve8hosd3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: You just made my day